# 1 query to select multiple rows in the same table but in different category

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization

I have a PHP script that use 4 separate query to read the last 25 rows from one single mysql table (so a total of 100 rows).

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime <= 'xxx' AND name = 'john' AND category = 'cat1' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 25
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime <= 'xxx' AND name = 'doe' AND category = 'cat1' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 25
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime <= 'xxx' AND name = 'john' AND category = 'cat2' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 25
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime <= 'xxx' AND name = 'doe' AND category = 'cat2' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 25
```

I use 4 query because I have to read different records, based on: **name and category**, both are index. Datetime is also an index.

But this way is very slow (the table is about 60MB, 250K rows). I was wondering if this can be done with 1 single query in a faster way.

EDIT mysql table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data1` double NOT NULL,
  `data2` double NOT NULL,
  `data3` double NOT NULL,
  #....
  `data50` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `datetime` (`datetime`),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused do you want the last 25 by name and category ie 100 rows?

Comment: If it is slow, which it shouldn't be on such a small table, it is most likely due to lack of appropriate indices (try `(category, name, datetime)`). Show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement and `EXPLAIN` output for your query. You could `UNION ALL` the queries together or change `WHERE` clause to something like `WHERE datetime <= 'xxx' AND name IN ('john', 'doe') AND category IN ('cat1', 'cat2')`, but obviously your sort and limit would be over the combined `WHERE` clause, not each (name, category) combo.

Comment: how much time did you spent when run this query? 1 second? 5 seconds?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, I need to select a total of 100 rows

Comment: @user1191247 category, name, datetime and indices already. i've added the table structure

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan it takes about 2-3 seconds, but this a query that i need to run very often (for batch tasks)

Comment: Composite index as suggested, not just single column indices. Please add `EXPLAIN` output to your question.

Comment: @ipel You should go back over the [questions you have asked](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2580729/ipel?tab=questions) and [accept (where appropriate)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or give feedback on the answers.

Comment: EVERSQL.com can help you. IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the queries together you can use [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to combine the results of the queries together:

```sql
(
    SELECT *
    FROM `table`
    WHERE datetime <= 'xxx' AND name = 'john' AND category = 'cat1'
    ORDER BY datetime DESC
    LIMIT 25
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT *
    FROM `table`
    WHERE datetime <= 'xxx' AND name = 'doe' AND category = 'cat1'
    ORDER BY datetime DESC
    LIMIT 25
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT *
    FROM `table`
    WHERE datetime <= 'xxx' AND name = 'john' AND category = 'cat2'
    ORDER BY datetime DESC
    LIMIT 25
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT *
    FROM `table`
    WHERE datetime <= 'xxx' AND name = 'doe' AND category = 'cat2'
    ORDER BY datetime DESC
    LIMIT 25
)
```

Note the individual queries need to be enclosed in parentheses, due to the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses.

Add a [composite index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX (category, name, datetime);
```

and you can DROP the single column index on `category` as it is the first column in this new index.

Comment: Thank you very much! i'm testing it right now. Does the order of the composite index matter?

Comment: For this query, it probably won't make any difference which way around you have category and name, but datetime should be at the end.

Comment: if I understood compsite index correctly, in this case I should move where clauses to follow the composite index order, so: WHERE category = 'cat2' AND name = 'doe' AND datetime <= 'xxx'

Comment: It makes no difference what order the columns are in, in the where clause. The optimizer will make its own decisions about the order of things.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a single query by allocating a row number for example

```
create table t(id int,category varchar(4),name varchar(20));
insert into t values
(1,'cat1','john'),(2,'cat1','john'),(3,'cat1','john'),(20,'cat1','john'),(30,'cat1','john'),
(4,'cat2','john'),(5,'cat2','john'),(6,'cat2','john'),(50,'cat2','john'),
(7,'cat1','doe'),(8,'cat1','doe'),(9,'cat1','doe'),
(10,'cat2','doe'),(11,'cat2','doe'),(12,'cat2','doe'),(120,'cat2','doe');

with cte as(
  select *,
  row_number() over (partition by name,category order by id desc) rn
  from t
  where id < 20 and name in('john','doe') and category in('cat1','cat2'))
select * from cte 
  where rn < 3
  order by name,category;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/05tdde0k

You need to test for yourself if this is quicker than what you have